# flutter videoplayer not working on smartphones

Tags: flutter, caching, video, flutterflow

i have custom videoplayer, i use flutterflow, and when i use runmode everything work perfectly but when i download this app with player to my phone, its broke, to insert videoUrls into player i use this logic: on page load i use apicall to take list of urls, then i update appstate with this urls and pass it to my player, here is my code:

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:cached_video_player_fork/cached_video_player.dart';

class CustomVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomVideoPlayer({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.videoUrls,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final List<String> videoUrls;

  @override
  _CustomVideoPlayerState createState() => _CustomVideoPlayerState();
}

class _CustomVideoPlayerState extends State<CustomVideoPlayer> {
  late List<CachedVideoPlayerController> _controllers;
  late List<String> _videoUrls;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoUrls = widget.videoUrls;
    _controllers = _videoUrls.map((url) {
      return CachedVideoPlayerController.network(url)..initialize();
    }).toList();

    _initializeVideoController(_currentIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var controller in _controllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _initializeVideoController(int index) {
    _controllers[index].play();
    _controllers[index].addListener(_onVideoEnd);
  }

  void _onVideoEnd() {
    if (_controllers[_currentIndex].value.position >=
        _controllers[_currentIndex].value.duration) {
      if (!_controllers[_currentIndex].value.isPlaying) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = (_currentIndex + 1) % _videoUrls.length;
          _initializeVideoController(_currentIndex);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _updateVideoController(int index) async {
    final videoFile =
        await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(_videoUrls[index]);
    final newController = CachedVideoPlayerController.file(videoFile)
      ..initialize();
    _controllers[index].dispose();
    _controllers[index] = newController;
    _initializeVideoController(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: widget.height ?? 200,
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: _controllers[_currentIndex].value.size?.width ?? 0,
          height: _controllers[_currentIndex].value.size?.height ?? 0,
          child: CachedVideoPlayer(_controllers[_currentIndex]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried using diffirent packages but always appears some error when i try to add caching to my player, all permissions to local storage are granted